# Generic stream / reader copying

Tags: scala

Working with streams, I wrote the following function that copies the content of an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream`:

```
def copy(input: InputStream, output: OutputStream, chunk: Int = 2048) {
  val buffer = Array.ofDim[Byte](chunk)
  var count  = -1

  while({count = input.read(buffer); count > 0})
    output.write(buffer, 0, count)
}
```

Writing the same function to copy the content of a `Reader` to a `Writer` yields extremely similar code - the only difference is the type of the `Array`.

I'm trying, but have so far been unable to, generalise my `copy` method.

I think I remember reading somewhere that I could describe a type by the methods it supports - accept any type that supports `read(buffer: Array[Byte])`, say. I might have made it up though, as I can't find it anymore.

I also thought of passing an implicit helper object, a bit like `Ordering` for the various collections' `sorted` method, but my brain is hitting a brick wall.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use an `InputStreamReader` and an `OutputStreamWriter` and wrap your copy function? Just use the same character encoding for both.

Comment: Do you mean that by using the same charset, decoding then encoding each character is basically a no-op? No reason this wouldn't work, but it's a bit of a hack, isn't it? Also, I'd rather avoid the cost of encoding and decoding if they're essentially useless...

Comment: In most Western languages, you're typically using UTF-8 by default, and in that case it's directly using the lowest 8 bits of the 32-bit char for mapping to bytes. In that case, masking them is the only overhead. I admit there are cases where you may need to take more care.

Comment: You can get the benefits of structural typing w/o the runtime penalty by using the type class pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you want a [structured type](http://proseand.co.nz/2013/05/19/static-typing-doesnt-have-to-suck-structural-typing/).  Just beware that this will utilize runtime reflection.  That shouldn't be a noticeable performance hit since you're likely doing I/O in this function, but just FYI.

```
def copy(input: { def read(buffer: Array[Byte]):Int }, ...
```

Comment: You can get the benefits of structural typing w/o the runtime penalty by using the type class pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a lot of the benefits of structured typing without incurring the runtime penalty using type classes. A type class is a concept. It's one approach to polymorphism. In particular, it's [ad-hoc polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class). Its the way we can get compile-time, statically checked duck typing!

Let's make `Reader[I]` and `Writer[O]` traits, where `I` and `O` are input and output stream types, respectively.

```
trait Reader[I] {
  def read(input: I, buffer: Array[Byte]): Int
}

trait Writer[O] {
  def write(output: O, buffer: Array[Byte], startAt: Int, nBytesToWrite: Int): Unit
}
```

We can now make a generic copy method that can operate on things that subscribe to these interfaces.

```
object CopyStreams {

  type Bytes = Int

  def apply[I, O](input: I, output: O, chunkSize: Bytes = 1024)(implicit r: Reader[I], w: Writer[O]): Unit = {
    val buffer = Array.ofDim[Byte](chunkSize)
    var count = -1

    while ({count = r.read(input, buffer); count > 0})
      w.write(output, buffer, 0, count)
  }
}
```

Note the implicit `r` and `w` parameters here. Essentially, we're saying that `CopyStreams[I,O].apply` will work iff there are `Reader[I]` and a `Writer[O]` values in scope. This will make us able to call CopyStreams(input, output) seamlessly.

We can use [context bounds](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html) and re-write the `apply` signature as

```
def apply[I: Reader, O: Writer](input: I, output: O, chunkSize: Bytes = 1024): Unit
```

We would then access our `Reader[I]` and `Writer[O]` instances using `implicitly[Reader[I]]` and `implicitly[Writer[O]]`, respectively. Note that this form is equivalent to the first form. The Scala compiler will actually re-write this context-bound version to the first one we presented.

Importantly, however, note that this implementation is generic. It operates on types that are independent of actual stream implementations.

In my particular use case, I needed to copy S3 objects to local files. So I made the following implicit values.

```
object Reader {

  implicit val s3ObjectISReader = new Reader[S3ObjectInputStream] {
    @inline override def read(input: S3ObjectInputStream, buffer: Array[Byte]): Int =
      input.read(buffer)
  }
}


object Writer {

  implicit val fileOSWriter = new Writer[FileOutputStream] {
    @inline override def write(output: FileOutputStream,
                               buffer: Array[Byte],
                               startAt: Int,
                               nBytesToWrite: Int): Unit =
      output.write(buffer, startAt, nBytesToWrite)
  }
}
```

So now I can do the following:

```
val input:S3ObjectStream = ...
val output = new FileOutputStream(new File(...))
import Reader._
import Writer._
CopyStreams(input, output)
// close and such...
```

And if we ever need to copy different stream types, we only need to write a new `Reader` or `Writer` implicit value. We can use the `CopyStreams` code without changing it!